# How to get several keys in a single description?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get several keys and values in a single description but I don't know how to do it, this is my code:

```py
  @commands.command(aliases=["pj"])
  async def personaje(self, ctx, personaje=None, member: discord.Member=None):
    if personaje is None:
      await ctx.send(":x: Debes proporcionar la id del personaje")
    else:
     if member is None:
       member = ctx.author
     if os.path.exists("json/Roleplay/Personajes/{member}/{idproof}.json".format(member=member.id, idpersonaje=personaje)): 
      with open("json/Roleplay/Personajes/{member}/{idproof}.json".format(member=member.id, idpersonaje=personaje), 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        Name = data["Name"]
        color = data["Color"]
        proof = data["proof"]
      
      for key in proof:
        color = int(color, 16)
        value = data["proof"][key]
        key = f"\n**{key}:** {value}"
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        embed=discord.Embed(description=f"**Name:**{Name}" + f"{'' if proof == {} else key}", color=color)
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.timestamp = timestamp
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
     else:
       await ctx.send(":x: Este personaje no existe")
       return
```

In theory what it would store in the json is this:

```py
{
  "Name": "Name",
  "Color": "0x00a6ff",
  "proof": {
    "A": "B",
    "C": "D",
    "E": "F"
  }
}
```

I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX5On.jpg

Comment: maybe first you should create full text and later send it.

Comment: in code you use `data["proof"]` but in JSON you shows `"Personalizado"` - so you use wrong name.

Comment: why not `for key,value in proof.items():`

Comment: did you run it in console to see if you get error messages? You use `data["proof"]` but you don't have `"proof"` in file. This should give error. You check value in `personalizado` but you never create this variable. This should give error.

Comment: I had it set to "personalizado" because I speak Spanish and I forgot to change that part.

Comment: I think you still should first get all values and convert to single string and later send it only once. At this moment you send in loop so you send every value separatelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run it but for me you have wrong indentations and you run `Embed` inside loop so in every loop you create new `Embed` with single line and you send it.

You should first create text with all informations and later send it.

And it doesn't need to check `proof = {}` because at start I set `text = ""` and if `prooof` is empty then after loop it will still `text = ""`

```
data = {
  "Name": "Name",
  "Color": "0x00a6ff",
  "proof": {
    "A": "B",
    "C": "D",
    "E": "F"
  }
}

name  = data["Name"]
color = data["Color"]
proof = data["proof"]

# - `for` loop -

text = ""

for key, value in proof.items():
    text += f"\n**{key}:** {value}"
    
print(text)

# - after `for` loop -

embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Name:**{name}{text}", color=color)
embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

With list comprehension

```
name  = data["Name"]
color = data["Color"]
proof = data["proof"]

# - `for` loop -

text = "".join(f"\n**{key}:** {value}" for key, value in proof.items())

print(text)

# - after `for` loop -

embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Name:**{name}{text}", color=color)
```